# Dynamically fill the ComboBox of an DataGridComboBoxColumn (WPF, DataGrid)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

in my WPF application, I have a DataGrid, which is bound to an ObservableCollection.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridTeilnehmer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" CellEditEnding="DataGridTeilnehmer_CellEditEnding" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Teilnehmer" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource TeilnehmerEditTemplate}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource TeilnehmerCellTemplate}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Pass" />
                    ...
```

The DataGridComboBoxColumn shall be filled with individual values for each row. The values depend on the entry of the first column. So, I would like to set the data in the CellEditEnding event like this:

```
    private void DataGridTeilnehmer_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!commiting)
        {
          commiting = true;
            DataGridTeilnehmer.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, false);
            commiting = false;

           // check, whether it is the first column that has been edited
           if (...)
             // get the list<string> for the combobox depending on the edited content
             // get the combobox of the current row and bind the calculated list<string> to it
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

EDIT: An example of what I am trying to achieve.

I have list of customers, which have individual tickets each. When the customer has been chosen in the first column, I want to load the ticket-list this customer has and load it into the next column - the combobox column.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

If you bound your datagrid to an ObservableCollection and your object implements INotifyPropertyChanged you can achieve what you need without using cell editending event.

In your model just check the value of your first column then set others columns values:

```
private string _firstColumn;
public string FirstColumn
{
    get { return _firstColumn; }
    set { 
         _firstColumn = value; 
         if(value == ...)
         //set other properties
         ...
         //notify the change
         OnPropertyChanged("FirstColumn"); }
}
```

when your datagridrow lost focus all the new values will be notified to the datagrid

Comment: But I need to get the items to the combobox-list. The combobox-list is the one which shall be changed dynamically and I have no idea who to set it.

Comment: Sorry @Aaginor if I misunderstand your question I'll delete the answer, can you provide an example?